# LinQ query select DataRow from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable, datarow

I have a linq query:

```
var dataPerDay = (from myRow in eartTideDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  where myRow.Field<string>(1) == date
                  select myRow);
```

Simply, I want to change the dataPerDay from `var` to `DataRow[]` but I can't do this. I already search in some website but I did not found something match with my case.

I just want to make something like this (see the // marks):

```
DataRow[] dataPerDay = (from myRow in eartTideDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                        where myRow.Field<string>(1) == date
                        select myRow)//Action Like => .ToDataRow()//;
```

How to to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ToArray()

```
   DataRow[] dataPerDay = (from myRow in eartTideDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                where myRow.Field<string>(1) == date
                                select myRow).ToArray();
```

Comment: Well, that's looks simpler than I thoughts.
Thanks dude.

Comment: Yes. But system said that I must wait for some minutes to accept.